# url is right but site redirects

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, magento

When I search for my site through google I can easily see my site, all the content being pulled correctly for the rich snippet. However if I click on the link from google itself, it sends me directly to my homepage and not the actual url the would be coming from the search. However If i look at the cached version or copy and paste the url google wants to send me to the link is displayed correctly. This is a Magento Based site,

Thanks,

Comment: Check your .htaccess file to make sure there is nothing strange in there.